# A git-svn checkout peculiarity

Tags: git, git-svn

My git-svn work flow is as follows:

Production code goes in master, off which I do my git svn dcommits/rebase.  I work on feature/topic branches, and continue to rebase -i to master and merge until I'm ready to bring those into master and subsequently push to svn trunk using dcommit.

*I can usually do `git checkout -` to checkout the previous branch I was on.*

For some reason though, when I do `git svn rebase`, and then try to git checkout to my previous branch, it does not work (it just stays in master).  That is, lets say I do:

```
(master)$ git checkout -b my-feature-branch
```

I do some work on that branch, then commit

```
(my-feature-branch)$ git commit -am "Some work"
```

I then want to bring in the latest changes, and the quickly change back to my branch:

```
(my-feature-branch)$ git checkout master
(master)$ git svn rebase
```

This brings in the latest svn trunk changes into master.  Now I just want to quickly change back to my topic branch.

```
(master)$ git checkout -
```

At this point, the branch checkout stays as master.  I'm guessing some sort of operation is popping off the last branch I worked on, but I don't know about the internals to know this for sure.

So my question is, does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `git checkout -`, `git` consults the file `.git/logs/HEAD` to find the last branch that you checked out.

When you run `git svn rebase`, this triggers the `cmd_rebase` function in the `git-svn` command, which in turns calls:

```
command_noisy(rebase_cmd(), $gs->refname);
```

This calls `rebase_cmd`, which looks like this:

```
sub rebase_cmd {
        my @cmd = qw/rebase/;
        push @cmd, '-v' if $_verbose;
        push @cmd, qw/--merge/ if $_merge;
        push @cmd, "--strategy=$_strategy" if $_strategy;
        push @cmd, "--preserve-merges" if $_preserve_merges;
        @cmd;
}
```

So the `git` command line built by this chain looks something like:

```
git rebase $gs->refname
```

(where `$gs->refname` would be substitute with a branch name.)  And from the `git-rebase` man page:

> If <branch> is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git checkout  
>   before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

Since the `rebase` command specifies a branch name, `rebase` performs a checkout, which appends an entry to `.git/logs/HEAD` *even if you are already on that branch*.  This is why the target of `git checkout -` is not what you expect after running `git svn rebase`.

**UPDATE** I may be wrong about *why* rebase is performing the checkout, but if you examine `.git/logs/HEAD` you can see clearly that rebase *is* performing (multiple) checkouts.  For example, if I have a branch `master` and a branch `b1` (descended from `master`), and then do:

```
git checkout master
git rebase b1
```

I end up with the following in the the log:

```
6240c11... c4bfd14... Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com> 
  1352952244 -0500  checkout: moving from b1 to master
c4bfd14... 6240c11... Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com> 
  1352952260 -0500  checkout: moving from master to 6240c1154706c675d19d771ad36aebc2658a5df8^0
6240c11... 6240c11... Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com> 
  1352952260 -0500  rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Actually, the git rebase command isn't providing <branch>, it's only providing <upstream>, so that part of the man page doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm actually not sure that's the case.  The wording in the `git rebase` man page suggests that you can specify `branch` withouting providing `upstream`, but maybe I'm misreading it.  If you know the correct answer, please post it here because I'm curious!

Comment: In this case, the code in git-svn makes me strongly believe that <upstream> is being provided because a few lines earlier git-svn refers to $gs->refname as "Remote Branch".

Answer (score 1):

This actually doesn't seem to have anything to do with git-svn, and is just a side-effect of rebasing in git. A `git rebase` seems to imply re-checking out the current branch. To prove this to your self, use the following commands:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout HEAD~1
 # A bunch of stuff about being in detached HEAD mode.
$ git checkout -b foo
$ git rebase master
$ git checkout -
 Already on 'foo'
```

This is because `git rebase` detaches HEAD using `git checkout -q "$onto^0"`. If you check .git/logs/HEAD after running the above commands, you'll see entries that state "moving from foo to 876AF98", followed by "rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/foo".